# how to transform ABP from promela to microclr?

Tags: modeling, promela

I've prepared an ABP model in Promela modeling language. But I'd need some help with rewriting it in another modelling language - mCRL. I do not have any experience in it. Could someone, please, show me a way to start, or point me to good tutorial for mCRL ?
Anyway, is there a difference in code between mCRL and mCRL2 ?

my code in promela:

```
mtype = { msg, ack }
chan to_sender = [2] of { mtype, bit };
chan to_recvr  = [2] of { mtype, bit };


active proctype Sender()
{
  bit s_out=0, s_in;
  do
  :: to_recvr!msg,s_out ->
     if
     :: to_sender?ack,s_in ->
        if
        :: s_in == s_out ->
end:         s_out = !s_out
        :: else -> 
            skip
        fi
     :: timeout
     fi
  od
}

active proctype Receiver()
{ 
  bit s_in, s_exp = 0;
  do
  :: to_recvr?msg,s_in ->
       to_sender!ack,s_in;
     if
     :: s_in == s_exp ->
end:       s_exp = !s_exp
     :: else -> 
        skip
     fi
  :: to_recvr?msg,s_in -> skip
  od
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mCRL is not actively supported anymore. I think it does not even compile with the newest GCC. 
There is actually an example ABP model in the mCRL2 sources: https://svn.win.tue.nl/repos/MCRL2/trunk/examples/academic/abp/abp.mcrl2.